# How do I pull props down into a component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, mapping, react-props

I'm creating a simple application that creates 'cards' by mapping through work orders (the first API). Through this API, there is a `workersId` that is needed to fetch the workers data from the second API.

This is my App.js

```js
  class App extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
      super(props);

      this.state = {
          orders:[],
          workersData: []
      };
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    fetch('https://www.hatchways.io/api/assessment/work_orders')
      .then(res=> res.json())
      .then(({ orders }) => {
        this.setState({
          orders: orders
        }, () => {
          this.state.orders.map(order => {
            fetch(`https://www.hatchways.io/api/assessment/workers/${order.workerId}`)
              .then(response=> response.json())
              .then(workersData => {
                this.setState({
                  workersData: workersData
                })
              })
          })
        });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
      });
  }

  render(){
    const { orders, workersData } = this.state;
      return(
       <CardList orders={ orders } workersData={ workersData } />
      );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I am carrying the 'orders' and 'workersData' props into my 'CardList' component so that I can try to map through each piece of data and place it in individual cards.

```js
const CardList = props => {
    console.log(props) //<-- this contains the 'orders' and 'workersData'

    const workOrderJsx = props.orders.map( order => (
        <Col key={ order.id } md={6} >
            <Card order={order} />
        </Col>
    ))

    return (
        <ListGroup>
            <MDBContainer fluid={true} >
                <MDBRow>
                    {workOrderJsx}
                </MDBRow>
            </MDBContainer>
        </ListGroup>
    );
}

export default CardList;
```

This all works great, but the problem I'm facing is that, by mapping through the orders, I only get cards with the orders on them. How can I also simultaneously retrieve the workers info that corresponds to the `id` in the `orders` object?

```js
const Card = props => {
    console.log(props) //<-- only order data

    let date = new Date( props.order.deadline * 1000 );
    const newTime = date.toLocaleString()

    return (
        <div className="card-container">
            <h1 className="order-name">{props.order.name}</h1>
            <p className="ml-5 mr-4">{props.order.description}</p>
            <div>
                <h5> Worker: {props.order.workerId} </h5> //<-- this is where I need the workers info to go
            </div>
            <p className="date">{newTime}</p>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Card;
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but it looks like you would get the `workersData` for one order only in your App component's state. Rather you'd want `this.setState(state => ({ workersData: [...workersData, newWorkerData]))`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are overwriting your workersData in your map at the fetch call. You should copy the existing workerData from previous loop iterations and combine it with the current iteration's workerData.

```
componentDidMount(){
    fetch('https://www.hatchways.io/api/assessment/work_orders')
      .then(res=> res.json())
      .then(({ orders }) => {
        this.setState({
          orders: orders
        }, () => {
          this.state.orders.map(order => {
            fetch(`https://www.hatchways.io/api/assessment/workers/${order.workerId}`)
              .then(response=> response.json())
              .then(workersData => {
                this.setState({
                  workersData: [...this.state.workersData, workersData]
                })
              })
          })
        });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
      });
  }
```

Then you can pass the workers data object into your card component along with the orders. Within the card component, you can lookup the worker info by order id in the workerData object.

Comment: I didn't have a problem passing workerData to my `CardList` component. I did implement the spread operator in there like you suggested, but my outcome in my `Card` component is still the same. It's only the `order` prop being sent through. It also continues to overwrite

Comment: You passed it like this? <Card order={order} workersData={props.workersData}/>

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is find the worker that corresponds to the order in your map function.

I guess your code would need to look something along those lines.

```
const CardList = props => {
  console.log(props) //<-- this contains the 'orders' and 'workersData'

  const findWorker = (id) => props.workersData.find(worker => worker.id === id);

  const workOrderJsx = props.orders.map(order => {
    const worker = findWorker(order.id);
    return (
      <Col key={order.id} md={6} >
        <Card order={order} worker={worker}/>
      </Col>
    )
  })

  return (
    <ListGroup>
      <MDBContainer fluid={true} >
        <MDBRow>
          {workOrderJsx}
        </MDBRow>
      </MDBContainer>
    </ListGroup>
  );
}

export default CardList;
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all your multiple requests to get workerData for each order are always get overridden with the new response which means your workerData will be containing data for only last order. So you should use Object there where every workerData will be put against each order.
Structure should be like `{ [orderWorkerId]: fetchedWorkerData}`

Then in your map method you can get specified workerData on the basis of order.workerId and pass it to the component where you’ll get correct data for every order. Hope this helps :)

**Further Details:**

In your API call for fetching workersData, do it like this:

`this.setState({workersData: { ...this.state.workersData, [order.workerId]: workersData }`

In this way you can maintain all your workerData against order.workerId. After that in you map method for orders do it like this:

`<Card order={order} workerData={props.workersData[order.workerId]} />`

In this way you’ll get related workerData to your order in you Card component and you can use it as you want. :)

Comment: Can you specifiy a little more. I'm not fulling understanding where Object would go